# How to run Markdown Extra on command line?

Tags: command-line, markdown, stdio

I realized I really need table support. And Markdown Extra offers it.

The problem is Markdown Extra (PHP) doesn't work in the command line. I have many a shell script which utilizes original markdown's stdio piping feature. I don't know PHP well, so maybe I don't know the right way. How can I run Markdown Extra on command line? I only need support for tables, so you can suggest other implementations.

Answer (score 1):

[Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) is a very good Markdown tool which support all the formats from Markdown Extra and can be used on the command line.